# Http request return string instead of observable with @angular/http

Tags: angular

Is it possible to have a function of returning type string, and return a string from http request in angular 2-4?

```
public getToken() : string {
    return this.http.get(`http://example.com/api/v1`, { params: this.queryParams })
                    .map(data => {
                                  let access = <Access>data.json();
                                  return access.AccessToken;
                                });
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: There is a way to make a sync HTTP with plain JS or other packages, but not with `HttpModule` or `HttpClientModule`, and there aren't many good reasons to use sync calls, especially in production code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks :)

Comment: Use `async` functions to embrace promises in synchronous-like manner.